# Match PHPDoc comments with Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, docblocks

I use the Javascript Syntax Highlighter built by Alex Gorbatchev

https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/SyntaxHighlighter/

I am trying to add support for PHPDoc comments, the PHP brush currenty matches singline and multiline comments but inside of comments when there is something like `@author` I would like to wrap that in a seperate class like other Syntax editors do.

I am trying to use this Regex

```
"\\s@[A-Za-z]+"
```

I tried testing it here
http://regexpal.com/?flags=ims&regex=%22%5C%5Cs%40%5BA-Za-z%5D%2B%22&input=%0A%40author%0A

But I cannot tell if it is working, can someone help me or let me know if that will match correctly

Comment: You don't need the double quotes in the regex box, nor should you need to escape the backslashes. You probably want this: http://regexpal.com/?flags=ms&regex=%5Cs%2A%40%5Ba-z%5D%2B%0A&input=%40author%0A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you're after is:

```
"\\s*@[A-Za-z]+"
```

Note the `*` after the `\s` (0 or more whitespace characters).

Additionally, RegexPal is not showing your match because it uses the literal regular expression, not the string version, so you should enter

```
\s*@[A-Za-z]+
```

in the top box, like [this example](http://regexpal.com/?flags=ims&regex=%5Cs%2A%40%5BA-Za-z%5D%2B%0A&input=%40author%0A). Note how the matched portion of the lower box is highlighted.